# How to show that matrices maintain linearity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it enough to show that the rules of matrices hold with adittion and scalar multiplication to prove that the map that sends a linear transformation to its matrix representation is a linear transformation itself? If not, can I see how it is shown then? Thanks

Comment: You have to show that the matrix associated to the sum of two linear transformation is actually the sum of the matrices associated to the two linear transformations. And you have also to prove that the matrix associated to a linear transformation $\lambda T$ given by the product of a scalar $\lambda$ and a linear transformation $T$ is given by the product of $\lambda$ and the matrix associated to $T$.

Comment: Yes but how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming we have a finitely dimensional vector spaces **S** and **W**, we know there is a basis of these vector spaces. Because of this, the linear transformation **T** is uniquely determined by the coefficients of the linear combination which is expressed in a transformation matrix with respect to the basis $\alpha$ for **S** and $\beta$ for **W**, that is:

$$\textbf{T} : \textbf{S} \rightarrow \textbf{W} $$
Then $\vec{x}$ is some vector in $\textbf{S}$ so we have:
$$\vec{x} = a_1\alpha_1 + \cdots + a_n\alpha_n$$
And the linear transformation takes vectors from **S** to **W** then the mapped vector $\vec{y}$ in **W** can be expressed in terms of the basis vectors $\beta$:
$$\vec{y} = b_1\beta_1 + \cdots + b_k\beta_k$$
Then the linear transformation is:
$$T(\vec{x}) = T(a_1\alpha_1 + \cdots +a_n\alpha_n)$$
And by linearity we have:
$$ = a_1T(\alpha_1) + \cdots + a_nT(\alpha_n)$$
Then by the basis $\beta$ we have:
$$ = a_1(b_{11}\beta_1 + \cdots + b_{1k}\beta_k) + \cdots + a_n(b_{k1}\beta_1 + \cdots + b_{kk}\beta_k)$$
And these coefficients are the entries in the transformation matrix with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: I added proper use of \cdots to the answer.  I noticed that you put extraneous curly braces after the Greek letters and in at least one other place, writing \alpha{} and \beta{} instead of \alpha and \beta.  What was the purpose of that? $\qquad$